# How can I get an element inside an array/element by ObjectId

Tags: c#, mongodb, compass

I have a question I couldn't solve. I have an Order element with Products array inside it. Like that:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("5ea0bfa85422e4537478312f"),
    label: "Order 01",
    status: {
       _id: ObjectId("5ea0bfa85422e4537478311a"),
       actual: "Created",
    }
    products: [
        {
           _id: ObjectId("5ea0bfa85422e4537478312e"),
           description: "Product 1"
        },
        {
           _id: ObjectId("5ea0bfa85422e4537478312d"),
           description: "Product 2"
        }
    ]
},
{
    _id: ObjectId("5ea0bfa85422e4537478312c"),
    label: "Order 02",
    status: {
       _id: ObjectId("5ea0bfa85422e4537478311b"),
       actual: "Accepted",
    }
    products: [
        {
           _id: ObjectId("5ea0bfa85422e4537478312b"),
           description: "Product 3"
        },
        {
           _id: ObjectId("5ea0bfa85422e4537478312a"),
           description: "Product 4"
        }
    ]
}
```

My classes are like this:

```
public class Order
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
}

public class Status
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Actual { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I want to run a query to return **The Order which contains an specific Product or Status** by it's ObjectId. Here is an Example about how I query for Product 3:

```
//var query = "{Product.Description: 'Product 3'"}"; // it works
var query = "{Status.Id: '5ea0bfa85422e4537478311a' }";   // DIDN'T work
var query = "{Product.Id: '5ea0bfa85422e4537478312b'}";   // ALSO DIDN'T work
orders.Find(query).ToList();
```

So, how to query these orders, by the inner element ID (Status) or by any of the array elements (Products).

Answer (score 0):

This is how its done in javascript

```
const query = `{"products":{ $elemMatch: { _id: ${Product.Id} } } }`;
orders.Find(query).ToList()
```

you have to use $elemMatch inside the "products" to find the orders having products with the required Id

See if this helps.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/

Comment: Worked using like that: ```{$elemMatch: { _id: new ObjectId('" + pedidoId + "')}}```